# Custom JacksonJaxbJsonProvider not throwing exception properly

Tags: json, exception, jackson, jax-rs

I have created a custom JacksonJaxbJsonProvider as below.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JacksonJsonProvider() {
        super();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule("jacksonJsonModule", null));
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT);
        //mapper.
        //mapper.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(Feature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, true);
        mapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, false);
        mapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        super.setMapper(mapper);
    }

}
```

In my code I throw WebApplicationException with errorMsg and errorCode.

When I use "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" and throw a WebApplicationException I get proper exception response as below

```
{
errorMsg: "Invalid input value passed, please correct the value"
errorCode: 400
}
```

But when I use above mentioned JacksonJsonProvider and throw an exception I always get 500 Internal server error. :(

I am missing some configuration setting. Please help me in figuring this out.

Thanks,
Pratz.

-----Edit-----
Sorry for the comment formatting. I am writting the same thing here for better code format.

In my resource, which has @Path annotation, I just throw an exception. It looks something like this

```
@ GET
@ Path("/{id}")
public User getUser(@ PathParam("id") Long userId) { 
    try {
        userService.getUser(userId);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new (Response.status(statusCode).entity(new ErrorResource("User not found.", Status.BAD_REQUEST..getStatusCode())).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: and where exactly do you throw the exception?

Comment: In my resource, which has @Path annotation, I just throw an exception. It looks something like this

inline `@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public User getUser(@PathParam("id") Long userId) { 
 try {
  userService.getUser(userId);
 } catch(Exception e) {
  throw new (Response.status(statusCode).entity(new ErrorResource("User not found.", Status.BAD_REQUEST..getStatusCode())).build());
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by debugging JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo method. I have one errorResource class which gets populated with proper error message and error code but this class was missing a default constructor so my custom JacksonJsonProvider was failing in creating an instance.
Now one question that still remains open is that it was working with default JacksonJsonProvider but not with custom JacksonJsonProvider but as of now I will live with it :)

Thanks,
Pratz